# angular material 2 calendar

Tags: angular, calendar, angular-material

I started with angular a few months ago, I like it very much but I still don't completely master it hehe, I have a doubt about the new calendar that has come out with material 2 recently, I'm trying to give color to the days depending on whether or not they're available, but I can't find the way to do it without using jquery, is there any function of this new calendar that allows to do it? 
Thank you

Comment: Check out the following link: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar#getting-started. It might be helpful.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, I have read the documentation of the calendar you've linked and it says that "this library is not optimised for mobile." I don't know if it will work with my responsive design.